# Redmine: Almost all plugins error 500

Tags: raspberry-pi, redmine, raspberry-pi2, redmine-plugins

I installed Redmine on my Raspberry Pi 2. I tried to install some plugins, but almost all plugin causes Error 500.

```
Redmine version 2.5.2.devel 
Ruby version 2.1.5-p273 (2014-11-13) [arm-linux-gnueabihf]            
Rails version 4.1.8
```

I only tried compatible plugins and I can't find the log files (I searched through the entire redmine directory)

What goes wrong?
And should I upgrade to V 3.x?

Comment: Without logs, it's impossible to know what's wrong. By default Redmine creates logs in the `log` directory inside the Redmine directory. Check there and edit your question to add logs.

Comment: @Holger There isn't any 'log' dir inside Redmine directory and when I make one and restart Redmine it's still empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running an old version of Redmine. You should install the new version which is 3.3.2. After installing the new version of Redmine you should have a log directory in the Redmine installation folder. Inside the log folder there should be a production.log file which has the log information.

Comment: Maybe you are right and the old version causes the error. Unfortunately I can't upgrade it yet, becouse as I found the newer Ruby and Rail versions need heavier equipment and Redmine already slow on this version (sometimes 30s loadtimes)